# Site has been visited many times by Ip address start with 172.31

Tags: ip, ip-address

I found that a lot of ip address start with 172.31 just visited my site.

I have searched for a while ,and found these maybe private ip address.

Can any friend let me know,what dose private ip address visit my site mean ?where are these ip address from ?By myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

172.31.x.y is within the private address range 172.16.0.0/16 from RFC 1918 that are *not* routed over the Internet. Accordingly, some host on your LAN is accessing the site, or possibly there's a reverse proxy.

In any case, we cannot tell you what is in your network.